# Test if the correct data is being sent to view

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, chai

Function that i want to test:

```
const homepageGet = (req, res, next) => {
    Product.find(function (err, products) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            next(err);
        } else {
            res.render('allProducts', { title: res.__('allProducts.title'), response: res, products: products });
        }
    });
};
```

I want to test if this function is actually sending products to the view. This is the test i wrote:

```
describe('Home page with all products', () => {
    it('shows all products', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/')
            .end((err, response) => {
                response.body.should.have.property('products');
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

This test fails and shows the following error message:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected {} to have property 'products'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `res.render` function renders html view and send it to client, this means the `response.body` is html text. You can use `should.have.property` function on an Object not on a text.

Comment: Try `res.json({products})`